# Counting the columns in sheet1 and pasting their result in a table in sheet 2

Tags: vba, excel

I have two sheets. sheet1 is Evaluation and sheet2 is the result sheet.

From the Evaluation sheet1, I would like to count the number of "OK" in Column S and T and count the number of "Invalid" in the column R.

These counted values are to be entered In the sheet2 result , in their corresponding columns.

I was working with this code and It worked completely fine.

But now, when I run the code, number of OK in the column S and T and number of Invalid in the column R are not counted.

Here is the Code I am trying to work with

```
Sub result()
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim cnt As Integer
Dim cntU, CntS, cntT As Integer
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim totalrows, n As Long
Set sht = Sheets("Result")
Sheets("Evaluation").Select
totalrows = Range("A5").End(xlDown).Row
n = Worksheets("FC_SCR Evaluation").Range("A5:A" & totalrows).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).count
For i = 2 To WorksheetFunction.count(sht.Columns(1))
cntT = 0
cntU = 0
CntS = 0
' get the current week of column A of result sheet
If sht.Range("A" & i) = Val(Format(Now, "WW")) Then Exit For
Next i
' if column A of result sheet and Column x of fc sheet are same, then count the mentioned parameters
 For j = 5 To WorksheetFunction.CountA(Columns(23))
 If sht.Range("A" & i) = Range("X" & j) And Range("T" & j) = "OK" Then cntT = cntT + 1
 If sht.Range("A" & i) = Range("X" & j) And Range("S" & j) = "OK" Then cntU = cntU + 1
 If sht.Range("A" & i) = Range("X" & j) And Range("R" & j) = "Invalid" Then CntS = CntS + 1
 ' print the counted value in corresponding column of result sheet
If cntT <> 0 Then sht.Range("D" & i) = cntT
If cntU <> 0 Then sht.Range("E" & i) = cntU
If CntS <> 0 Then sht.Range("C" & i) = CntS
If n <> 0 Then sht.Range("B" & i) = n
Next j
If cntT + cntU <> 0 Then
sht.Range("F" & i) = CntS / n
sht.Range("g" & i) = cntT / n
sht.Range("h" & i) = cntU / n
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Go through your program step by step, check the values of your variables at each step, find the point where it goes wrong and add it to your description. For example: "At this point of running the code the variable X has an unexpected value, and I don't know why". We will be glad to help you from this point on.

Comment: @DavidG Yeah will do It :)

Comment: 1) Use Long rather then Integer; 2) don't be afraid to break up your code with spaces to aid readability, and indentation is a must; 3) in your second loop you have not qualified all your ranges so they will apply to Evaluation sheet as you selected it earlier.

Comment: 4) In your second loop `i` never changes.

Comment: @SJR I changes in second loop